have top-level parser and subparsers act on the same variable
i have an ArgumentParser with sub-parsers. Some flags are common for all sub-parsers, and I would like to be able to specify them either before or after the sub-command, or even mix before and after (at the user's discretion).
Something like this:
$ ./test -v
Namespace(v=1)
$ ./test.py test -vv
Namespace(v=2)
$ ./test.py -vvv test
Namespace(v=3)
$ ./test.py -vv test -vv
Namespace(v=4)

So I tried something like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-v", action="count")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
sub = subparsers.add_parser("test")
sub.add_argument("-v", action="count")

print(parser.parse_args())

Running this program "test.py" gives me:
 ./test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-v] {test} ...

positional arguments:
  {test}

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -v

$ ./test.py test -h
usage: test.py test [-h] [-v]

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -v

$ ./test.py -v
Namespace(v=1)

$ ./test.py test -vv
Namespace(v=2)

cool.
but it also gives me:
$ ./test.py -vvv test
Namespace(v=None)
$ ./test.py -vv test -vv
Namespace(v=2)

less cool :-(
I also tried to specify parent-parsers explicitly:
common = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
common.add_argument("-v", action="count")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[common])
sub = parser.add_subparsers().add_parser("test", parents=[common])

print(parser.parse_args())

but the result is the same.
So, I guess that as soon as the test subparser kicks in, it resets the value if v to None.
How do I prevent this?
(I notice that How can I define global options with sub-parsers in python argparse? is similar, and the answer there suggests to use different dest variables for the top-level and the sub-level parser. i would like to avoid that...)

As my old answer says, giving the subparser argument priority (including the default) was an intentional choice (by the original author).  Different dest lets you choose which value you'll use - in post parsing code.  Rewriting the subparser Action subclass is possible for advanced programmers.

parents is just a short-cut way of defining Actions; otherwise it doesn't do anything special.  When specifying the same dest at main and sub levels, the program has to make some sort of choice.  The devs chose one option, which makes sense in many, but not all uses.  count doesn't get any special treatement.  You don't have to do everything within argparse.  Post-parsing code is allowed.

The desired behavior for action='count' as per the question is simply not possible using a single ArgumentParser (as of Python 3.12.3), because of how sub-namespace gets merged into the main namespace at the end.  Specifically, the internal _CountAction callable will find try to find the dest in the current namespace, set it to 0 if not already exist, and increment the value by 1.  However, the internal _SubparserAction callable will just naively merge the resulting values in (not an exact but very much related known issue).  You may verify this by tracing through the execution using following argparser (which is set up with additional default flags for disambiguation along with example input), and step through the debugger:
import argparse

common = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
common.add_argument("-v", action="count")
common.add_argument("-c", default="common")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[common])
parser.add_argument("-p", default="parser")
sub = parser.add_subparsers().add_parser("test", parents=[common])
sub.add_argument("-s", default="sub")

args = ['-v', '-v', 'test', '-v', '-v']

# demo
print(f"parser: {parser.parse_args(args)}")

Alternate to stepping through the debugger, insert print(namespace) above the linked lines for _CountAction.__call__ and print(f"{subnamespace} merging into {namespace}") before the for block in the second code block, will produce the following output:
Namespace(v=None, c='common', p='parser')
Namespace(v=1, c='common', p='parser')
Namespace(v=None, c='common', s='sub')
Namespace(v=1, c='common', s='sub')
Namespace(v=2, c='common', s='sub') merging into Namespace(v=2, c='common', p='parser')
parser: Namespace(v=2, c='common', p='parser', s='sub')

I've worked around this specific issue many years ago in a package I've written (specifically, this commit, which hinted at this very specific woe) by using a common parser and parse_known_args with the incoming arguments.  Since your final example already has a common parser, change the demo portion to be:
print(f"common: {common.parse_known_args(args)}")
print(f"parser: {parser.parse_args(args)}")

Should produce the following output:
common: (Namespace(v=4, c='common'), ['test'])
parser: Namespace(v=2, c='common', p='parser', s='sub')

Pick what you need from the known args of common (and ignore the remainder), and parse the list of args as normal with parser and use the rest of it as normal.

this works great...but now i've run into the problem that i also want to have different defaults per subcommand (but obviously this wasn't part of my question)

i guess the problem comes from the fact, that now all sub-parsers use the identical action (which owns the default value). however, the idea to use parse_known_args() to merge the flags is great.

Actions are copied by reference from parent.  Thus changing attributes like default individually is not an option.  Parents is just a convenience tool.  You could just as easily write your own utility function to create Actions, or use the good old copy-n-paste.

Yeah if the defaults are different you will need to disambiguate with a different dest, because it's not possible to workaround using the remainder of parse_known_args on a dummy, because note that the remainder only contains ['test'] (rather than ['test', '-v', ...] i.e. with trailing arguments), and that there are no other partial or iterative parsing methods available.

I know you want to avoid different dest (why?), but it sure seems like the simplest approach.  It gives you the most control.
In [4]: import argparse
   ...: 
   ...: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: parser.add_argument("-v", action="count", dest='foo', default=0)
   ...: 
   ...: subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
   ...: sub = subparsers.add_parser("test")
   ...: sub.add_argument("-v", action="count", dest='subfoo', default=0);

In [5]: args = parser.parse_args(['-vv', 'test']); args
Out[5]: Namespace(foo=2, subfoo=0)

In [6]: args.count= args.foo+args.subfoo; args
Out[6]: Namespace(foo=2, subfoo=0, count=2)

In [7]: args = parser.parse_args(['test', '-vvv']); args
Out[7]: Namespace(foo=0, subfoo=3)

In [8]: args.count= args.foo+args.subfoo; args
Out[8]: Namespace(foo=0, subfoo=3, count=3)

In [9]: args = parser.parse_args(['-v','test', '-vvv']); args
Out[9]: Namespace(foo=1, subfoo=3)

In [10]: args.count= args.foo+args.subfoo; args
Out[10]: Namespace(foo=1, subfoo=3, count=4)

As noted before, the subparser value has priority. When invoked, the subparser gets a fresh Namespace, rather than inheriting the one that the main parsers has been using.  On return, that sub-namespace is used to update the main Namespace.  There are arguments for and against this choice.
By choosing different dest, you retain control over which parser has priority.  Or in the case of an action like count the ability to treat them equally.  Shoot you could even do args.diff = args.foo - args.subfoo!

i would like to avoid the different dests, as it requires manually handling all the options (again). in practice my solution does something like this (using prepending a dash (-v) as the dest for the flag in the top-level parser, so i can easily match the subparser value with the top-level value without running into the danger of nameclashes; and then merge them automatically); but it's a bit ugly.

For the sake of completeness, I'm posting my actual solution, which is heavily guided by the accepted answer:
def add_common_args(parser, defaults={}):
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose" action="count")
    parser.add_argument("--foo")
    parser.set_defaults(**defaults)

common = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
add_common_args(common)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[common])
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
p = subparsers.add_parser(subparsers, "test")
add_common_args(p, defaults_test)
p.add_argument("--bar")

# parse common args and subparser args separately
common_args = common.parse_known_args()[0]
args = parser.parse_args()

# fix common args
for k, v in common_args._get_kwargs():
    if v is None:
        continue
    setattr(args, k, v)

The trick is (as suggested by metatoaster), to do a partial parsing that only recognizes the common arguments (ignoring anything unknown, like the sub-parser itself and sub-parser specific arguments; but accumulating count flags, and ensuring that for normal flags that last one wins).
So passing -v --foo A test -v --foo B will result in Namespace(v=2, foo='B', bar=None).
In order to achieve per-subparser defaults (which may be read from a configuration file, and are therefore unknown), the common arguments are implemented by a utility function add_common_args() (as per hpaulj suggestion), rather than sharing the common parser.
We need to special-case unset values from the common parser (if v is None: continue), so a default will not get overwritten with the unset value.
